# How to create a table in psql database using python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running this script and want to create a table by passing values in psql query using variables. So, that I can create multiple table in one go. But this `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(%s, %s)",[table_name, comp_schema])` line is throwing error. How can I write this query to create a table with the given schema?

```py
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(database="review_check", user = "xxx", password = "xxx",)
cur = conn.cursor()
print ("Opened database successfully")    


comp_schema = """
as_of_date DATE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
verified_reviews INTEGER,
lsa_total_reviews INTEGER
"""

table_name = 'comp_first'

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(%s, %s)",[table_name, comp_schema])

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS('comp_first',

Comment: See piro answer below for correct way to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's a couple of errors here, in both the SQL syntax and the Python:

`cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(%s, %s)",[table_name, comp_schema])`

should be

`cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s)"%(table_name, comp_schema))`

It might be easier during development to build the query in a separate variable first, then print it to see if it looks right:

```
test = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s)"%(table_name, comp_schema)
print(test)

>>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comp_first (
  as_of_date DATE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  verified_reviews INTEGER,
  lsa_total_reviews INTEGER
  )
```

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of string composition for the creation of dynamic queries. This is the route to `SQL` injection.  See @piro answer below for link on how to correctly do this.

Comment: My bad, fair enough! I wasn't thinking in the context of outside access to a system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `psycopg2.sql` module to compose a query dynamically. see https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html.